# Html jquery dynamic row

Tags: jquery, html

I have a situation where i need to add multiple addresses and address can have multiple 
phone number and FAX no. For example, the address1 can have 1 or more phone and fax numbers. How can I achieve this?

The code is below :http://jsfiddle.net/hfYbH/2/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Dynamic Row</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> 
<script language="javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
// generate new row
$('#addButton').on('click', function(event){
var newRow = '<tr><td><input type="text" name="" value="" id=""  ></td><td><input type="text" name="" value="" id="" size="4" ></td><td><input type="text" name="" value="" id="" size="4" ></td><td><a href="#" align=left id="addMore" >Add Phone and FAX</a></td></tr>';
$('#room').append(newRow);        
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <form name="formname" id="formid" >
<table width="42%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;"  id="room" >
  <tr>
    <td width="16%">Address</td>
    <td width="7%">Phone</td>
    <td width="8%">FAX</td>
    <td width="69%"><a href="#" align=left id="addButton" >Add Address</a></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="" value="" id=""  ></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="" value="" id="" size="4" ></td>


    <td><input type="text" name="" value="" id="" size="4" ></td>
    <td><a href="#" align=left id="addMore" >Add More items</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>  
<table><tr><td><input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn" /></td></tr></table>
</form>
```

Comment: Achieve what? What exactly do you ask here?

Comment: How can i add phone and Fax when clicking the add phone and fax?

Comment: Do you mean that you have to insert in a nested fashion inside every address?

Comment: it should be nested for example for address 1 it can have 1 or more phone/fax no.

Comment: is it possible that way ? or you suggest any other method ?

Comment: Anybody can let me kniw?

Answer (score 0):

I have edited a bit html and edited Javascript code which is as follows:

```
var rowColAdded = false;
$(document).ready(function(){
// generate new row
$('#addButton').on('click', function(event){
    rowColAdded = false;
var newRow = '<tr><td><input type="text" name="" value="" id=""  ></td><td><input type="text" name="" value="" id="" size="4" ></td><td><input type="text" name="" value="" id="" size="4" ></td><td><a href="#" align=left id="addMore" >Add More items</a></td></tr>';
$('#room').append(newRow);        
    });
$('#addMore').on('click', function(event){

var newCol = '<td width="8%">Phone&Fax</td>';
var newRow = '<td><input type="text" name="" value="" id="" size="4" ></td>';
    if(!rowColAdded)
    {
        rowColAdded = true;
    $('#colExpand').append(newCol);        
    $('#rowExpand').append(newRow);        
    }
    });

});
```

Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hfYbH/8/).

Hope this helps.